# Can CSS override the bold style of an existing <b> bold tag?

Tags: html, css, typography

I have a script that has a breadcrumb styled outside of my reach (core files), and I want to override all its styling using CSS. The text looks like this:

```
<div class="someclass">
<b>Some Text</b>
</div>
```

I want to style the `<div>` to make it ignore the bold tag. Is this possible without removing the `<b>` tag and just using external CSS?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes:

```
.someClass b {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Haha it's amazing how easy it was.. I have many things to learn :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large project with many font-weight: bold; references, you can override the eitre font:

```css
/* some core files */
b {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* latin */
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
                src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OUuhp.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }
        
        
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

/* no override */
body .someclass2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="someclass">
  <b>Some Text</b>
</div>

<div class="someclass2">
  <b>Some Text</b>
</div>

</body>
```

Usage:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```